# Passing Dynamic Value to Angular Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to pass a dynamic value to a custom angular directive. I am generating the value from a function and I want it to be resolved before the directive resolves; a first cursory pass at this looked like this on a DOM element:

```
my-directive="{{ myfunction() }}"
```

This resulted in the DOM looking the way it should:

```
my-directive="MYRESULTS"
```

However I find that the directive isn't seeing these results when it is run; it appears to be triggered before the value is set. Is there some way I can seed a custom value for my directive? Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: how did you implemented the bonding in your directive? did you use bindToController? scope? add more code please

Comment: It's bound by scope.

Comment: it's hard to answer with no more code from your implementation

Comment: if a function is going to produce the value, you can consider binding it directly with the directive using `&` binding

Comment: Thanks, I've seen some info on this however I'm trying to avoid editing the directive; otherwise I could just pass in a function and trigger it from within the actual directive.